# Пунктуация в цитате

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли поставлена пунктуация в оформлении цитат такого типа: "...!/?" (автор). Например,

"Зачем же гнаться по следам того, что уже давно окончено?" (Воланд).

У Розенталя есть [правило](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=166#pp166) с цитатой, которая оканчивается на точку и, понятно, что точка переносится.  «Значение Белинского в истории русской общественной мысли огромно» (Луначарский). Но распространяется ли это правило на восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, не очень понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справочник Лопатина, раздел "Пунктуация", § 147:

> Если цитата заканчивается вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, а
> также многоточием, то эти знаки сохраняют свое место (стоят перед
> закрывающей кавычкой). При перечислении примеров точка после
> закрывающей скобки заменяется на точку с запятой: *«Как ты таинственна,
> гроза!» (И. Бунин. Полями пахнет...); «Не покидайте своих
> возлюбленных. Былых возлюбленных на свете нет...» (А. Вознесенский.
> Поэмы. М., 2001. С. 5).*

Из формулировки можно сделать вывод, что если нет перечисления, то точка стоит так, как у вас в примере с Воландом.

Comment: @Sharon там нет примера именно с конструкцией *"...!/?" (Автор).*

Answer (score 1):

***"Зачем же гнаться по следам того, что уже давно окончено?"* (Воланд).**

Оформление правильное.

Ссылки на автора и источник цитирования заключаются в скобки, а точка, заканчивающая цитату, ставится после закрывающей скобки.

Еще пример: «Мыслить педагогически широко – это значит видеть в любом социальном явлении воспитательный смысл» (Азаров Ю. Учиться, чтобы учить // Новый мир. 1987. № 4. С. 242).

Если цитата заканчивается **вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, а также многоточием,** то эти знаки сохраняют свое место, стоят перед закрывающей кавычкой.

Например: «Не покидайте своих возлюбленных. Былых возлюбленных на свете нет...» (А. Вознесенский. Поэмы. М., 2001. С. 5).

Источник: https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/313-osnovnyesposobycitirovaniya.html

Пример: Мечты о воле, свободе проходят через всю поэзию XIX века: «Взойдёшь ли ты когда, Свобода, блеснёт ли луч твой золотой?» ( Ф.Тютчев).